The connector between Looker and appsheet is broken
The connector between looker and appsheet just broke. In no account and with no app does it work. Until a couple of hours ago it was working without problems.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1udn8NB4ZPWuH7hsJPUCvhmYQgf1ixXoJ/view?usp=sharing
The connector between looker and appsheet just broke. In no account and with no app does it work. Until a couple of hours ago it was working without problems.
